# How to sort 2 different values of JSON data?

Tags: php, json, sorting

Kindly help me with code that sort "Row" in descending order and "Column" in ascending order of below JSON Data.

```
$print = '{"Table":[
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A4","Row":12}, 
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A3","Row":11},
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A2","Row":9},
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A1","Row":8},  
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B4","Row":12},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B3","Row":11},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B2","Row":9},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B1","Row":8},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C4","Row":12},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C3","Row":11},  
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C2","Row":9},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C1","Row":8},
{"Column":5,"Length":1,"Number":"D4","Row":12},
{"Column":5,"Length":1,"Number":"D3","Row":11},
{"Column":5,"Length":1,"Number":"D2","Row":9},
{"Column":5,"Length":1,"Number":"D1","Row":8},
{"Column":6,"Length":1,"Number":"E4","Row":12},
{"Column":6,"Length":1,"Number":"E3","Row":11},
{"Column":6,"Length":1,"Number":"E2","Row":9},
{"Column":6,"Length":1,"Number":"E1","Row":8},
{"Column":7,"Length":1,"Number":"F4","Row":12},
{"Column":7,"Length":1,"Number":"F3","Row":11},
{"Column":7"Length":1,"Number":"F2","Row":9},
{"Column":7,"Length":1,"Number":"F1","Row":8},
{"Column":8,"Length":1,"Number":"G4","Row":12},
{"Column":8,"Length":1,"Number":"G3","Row":11},
{"Column":8,"Length":1,"Number":"G2","Row":9},
{"Column":8,"Length":1,"Number":"G1","Row":8},
{"Column":9,"Length":1,"Number":"H4","Row":12},
{"Column":9,"Length":1,"Number":"H3","Row":11},
{"Column":9,"Length":1,"Number":"H2","Row":9},
{"Column":9,"Length":1,"Number":"H1","Row":8},
{"Column":10,"Length":1,"Number":"I4","Row":12},
{"Column":10,"Length":1,"Number":"I3","Row":11},
{"Column":10,"Length":1,"Number":"I2","Row":9},
{"Column":10,"Length":1,"Number":"I1","Row":8},
{"Column":11,"Length":1,"Number":"J4","Row":12},
{"Column":11,"Length":1,"Number":"J3","Row":11},
{"Column":11,"Length":1,"Number":"J2","Row":9},
{"Column":11,"Length":1,"Number":"J1","Row":8},
{"Column":12,"Length":1,"Number":"K4","Row":12},
{"Column":12,"Length":1,"Number":"K3","Row":11},
{"Column":12,"Length":1,"Number":"K2","Row":9},
{"Column":12,"Length":1,"Number":"K1","Row":8},
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S4","Row":12},
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S3","Row":11},
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S5","Row":10},
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S2","Row":9},
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S1","Row":8}],"ResponseStatus":200,"Message":null}';
```

I want to group elements by "Row" which should be printed in descending order and "Column" of corresponding "Row group" should printed in ascending order. I want rest as given below.

```
$print = '{"Table":[
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A4","Row":12}, 
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B4","Row":12},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C4","Row":12},
{"Column":5,"Length":1,"Number":"D4","Row":12},
{"Column":6,"Length":1,"Number":"E4","Row":12},
{"Column":7,"Length":1,"Number":"F4","Row":12},
{"Column":8,"Length":1,"Number":"G4","Row":12},
{"Column":9,"Length":1,"Number":"H4","Row":12},
{"Column":10,"Length":1,"Number":"I4","Row":12},
{"Column":11,"Length":1,"Number":"J4","Row":12},
{"Column":12,"Length":1,"Number":"K4","Row":12},
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S4","Row":12},
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A3","Row":11},  
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B3","Row":11},  
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C3","Row":11},
{"Column":5,"Length":1,"Number":"D3","Row":11},
{"Column":6,"Length":1,"Number":"E3","Row":11},
{"Column":7,"Length":1,"Number":"F3","Row":11},
{"Column":8,"Length":1,"Number":"G3","Row":11},
{"Column":9,"Length":1,"Number":"H3","Row":11},
{"Column":10,"Length":1,"Number":"I3","Row":11},
{"Column":11,"Length":1,"Number":"J3","Row":11},
{"Column":12,"Length":1,"Number":"K3","Row":11},
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S3","Row":11},
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S5","Row":10},
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A2","Row":9},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B2","Row":9},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C2","Row":9},
{"Column":5,"Length":1,"Number":"D2","Row":9},
{"Column":6,"Length":1,"Number":"E2","Row":9},
{"Column":7"Length":1,"Number":"F2","Row":9},
{"Column":8,"Length":1,"Number":"G2","Row":9},
{"Column":9,"Length":1,"Number":"H2","Row":9},
{"Column":10,"Length":1,"Number":"I2","Row":9},
{"Column":11,"Length":1,"Number":"J2","Row":9},
{"Column":12,"Length":1,"Number":"K2","Row":9},
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S2","Row":9},
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A1","Row":8},  
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B1","Row":8},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C1","Row":8},
{"Column":5,"Length":1,"Number":"D1","Row":8},
{"Column":6,"Length":1,"Number":"E1","Row":8},
{"Column":7,"Length":1,"Number":"F1","Row":8},
{"Column":8,"Length":1,"Number":"G1","Row":8},
{"Column":9,"Length":1,"Number":"H1","Row":8},
{"Column":10,"Length":1,"Number":"I1","Row":8},
{"Column":11,"Length":1,"Number":"J1","Row":8},
{"Column":12,"Length":1,"Number":"K1","Row":8}, 
{"Column":13,"Length":1,"Number":"S1","Row":8}],"ResponseStatus":200,"Message":null}';
```

Kindly look into to "Row" which is printed descending order and "Column" in ascending order.

I used following code, but that helps to short only Row but "Columns" are not sorted correctly.

```
$json = json_decode($print, true);
usort($json['Table'], function($a, $b) { return $a['Row'] < $b['Row']; } );
$print = json_encode($json);
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `b - a` if its descending for row, and `a -b` for column:

```
usort($json['Table'], function($a, $b) {
    $diff = $b['Row'] - $a['Row'];
    if($diff) return $diff;
    return $a['Column'] - $b['Column'];
});
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CXq8K5)